# Validate dropdown list using required field validator not working

Tags: asp.net, dropdown, requiredfieldvalidator

I have an asp dropdown and I am trying to validate it but the validating is just not working.

My dropdown and validator:

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control"
    runat="server" ID="cmb_Addresses"
    ValidationGroup="ShippingAddress">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="cmb_Addresses" 
    ValidationGroup="ShippingAddress" 
    InitialValue="0" 
    Display="dynamic" 
    ErrorMessage='Please select an address' 
    runat="server"/>
```

And here is the method that populates the dropdown:

```
private void SetupAddresses()
{
    var accountService = new AccountService();
    var userService = new UserService();

    var username = userService.GetLoggedInUser();

    var addresses = accountService.GetAddressesForUser(username);

    cmb_Addresses.Items.Clear();
    cmb_Addresses.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("--Please Select--", "0"));

    foreach (var address in addresses)
    {
        cmb_Addresses.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(address.Name, GetAddressValue(address)));
    }
}
```

I have tried all the suggestions I have found on the net but they not working.

Oh, the method is called in a !IsPostback

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the correct `ValidationGroup` to the button that does the PostBack? Because I tested your snippet and it works.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="ShippingAddress" />
```

If you did add it to the button, there is probably a javascript error somewhere on the page that is interfering with the Validator. If there are errors the Validator won't work and the form is posted.